# How to know that login credential is wrong or right in selenium TestNG ?how to do negative testing?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, testng-dataprovider

If I trying to login in selenium with multiple credential and it is login successfully. But How I confirmed that those credential are right? or how to do negative testing in selenium? please help!!

Answer (score 0):

This you can do in several ways.

1. Define DataProvider with three inputs (username, password, isValidCreds). As you already know creds are valid or invalid, just pass true for isValidCreds in case of valid else false.
2. As we know, in case of invalid attempt, that would be failed login. Define dataProvider with two inputs (username and password). Enter both and click on Login.
   Wait for 20-30 seconds using ExplicitWait to get HomePage title or any element loaded specific to home page. If not loaded, treat that username and password combo is invalid..